# Using regular Google account as service account

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I have an application using Google Drive that must (a) not require user login and (b) populate a document that authorised users can view.

Because of this it appears that using a regular account as a service account is my only option, as described here https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts

> Use regular Google accounts as application-owned accounts
>
> You may create a regular Google account like any user would, by going
>   through the Google account sign-up flow or by creating an account on
>   your Google Apps domain. Make sure it is then never used by an actual
>   person but only by your application.
>
> To be able to access the account’s Drive programmatically you need to
>   manually go through the OAuth 2.0 web-server flow once and then store
>   or hard-code the user’s credentials, such as the refresh token, to be
>   able to programmatically access its Drive. For more information about
>   the web server flow for Drive, see Implementing Server-side
>   Authorization.

While it discourages user access, it doesn't ban it. However I am confused by the line

> you need to manually go through the OAuth 2.0 web-server flow once and
>   then store or hard-code the user’s credentials

There doesn't seem to be a documented way to do this (yes, I have searched) - could someone step me though it?

Comment: Hi green green grass, have you found a solution? I as well want to know how can I " manually go through the OAuth 2.0 web-server flow once and then store or hard-code the user’s credentials"...

Answer (score 2):

You don't use a regular account as a service account, these are different things. Each one is a type of **application-owned account**.

The **regular account** is just a normal Google account that your application uses. Since regular accounts require the manual authorization step (going to the browser, logging in to Google and authorizing your app), you need to do this manually the first time and then save the token. There's some examples in [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server). After you save the token, your app can authorize itself without your intervention.

The **service account** is an account that is not associated with an user and that do not require manual authorization. You can create a service account in the Developers Console as described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts). With this type of account, you use a private key file to authorize your app.

Unless you need access to the web interface of the account that will manage your files (for example, to buy more storage), I'd recommend using the service account, since it doesn't require the manual step.

Comment: Hi, does it mean that a Service Account cannot be accessed by the web interface? I want to have an application-owned account for users to download stuff and me to upload through the web interface, should I choose a regular acc or service acc?

Comment: yes, service accounts are used to access the resources programmatically (you can share a resource with regular accounts though, so they can access it in the browser)... i'm not sure what you mean by "an application-owned account for users to download stuff"